# python3 sort objects by multiple named attributes

Tags: sorting, python-3.x

I have a list of objects in Python 3.5.1 with several named attributes. The list represents a group of C variables and as such each object has three named attributes that correspond to three common base types: uint8, uint16, and uint32.

```
class variableList(object):
    def __init__(self, eight, sixteen, thirtytwo):
        self.size_8 = eight
        self.size_16 = sixteen
        self.size_32 = thirtytwo
```

The value of these named attributes is either `(Nonetype) None` or `(str)'E'`. Per object, only one of the named attributes will have some non-None value.

I want to sort this list of objects such that all objects with non-None value for size_32 are on top, followed by size_16, followed by size_8.

In python 2.7.1 I successfully used this, but it felt like black magic:

```
size_filtered_list = sorted(filtered_list, key=lambda y: (y.size_32, y.size_16, y.size_8))
```

but in 3.5.1 this no longer works. Suggestions?

Comment: If you define `__lt__` and  `__eq__` methods you could sort your variables without a `key` argument.  Because I am unfarmiliar with C could you explain basically what  `(str)'E'` would mean in python?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using effectively boolean flags as `None` and `'E'` rather than just using `False` and `True`? If you weren't using incompatible types, your sort could simplify to an import at the top of the file, `from operator import attrgetter`, with the sort: `sorted(filtered_list, key=attrgetter('size_32', 'size_16', 'size_8'))`, which works fine in all versions of Python because you're sorting comparable types.

Comment: Or if you add another variable as in `self.size_8_exist`, you can still use the same technique.

Answer (score 1):

You should move to using compatible types; sorting `None` and `'E'` is nonsensical, and while Python 2's "arbitrary but consistent" sort rules for incompatible types allows it, it's terrible practice. If the only values are `None` and `'E'`, then they're really just terrible versions of booleans; you could just as easily use `False` and `True` and your `key` function would work fine in both Py2 and Py3; you could even "optimize" a little with `operator.attrgetter`:

```
from operator import attrgetter

size_filtered_list = sorted(filtered_list, key=attrgetter('size_32', 'size_16', 'size_8'))
```

Alternatively, using the original `lambda` based code, you could make it work by replacing `None` with the empty string in the `key`, so you compare compatible types (while still treating the `None` as less than every other string):

```
size_filtered_list = sorted(filtered_list, key=lambda y: (y.size_32 or '', y.size_16 or '', y.size_8 or ''))
```

It's kind of silly, but so is using `None` and `'E'` for what amounts to boolean data.

Answer (score 0):

I would just implement the comparison operators for the class. Assuming you do not want to sort based on the values stored in each of these attributes, this implementation should work.

```
class variableList(object):
    def __init__(self, eight, sixteen, thirtytwo):
        self.size_8 = eight
        self.size_16 = sixteen
        self.size_32 = thirtytwo

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.size_8 is not None:
            return self != other
        elif self.size_16 is not None:
            return True if other.size_32 is not None else False
        else:
            return False

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.size_8 is not None:
            return other.size_8 is not None
        elif self.size_16 is not None:
            return other.size_16 is not None
        else:
            return other.size_32 is not None
```

And for completeness, you can also implement the greater than operator, but it is not necessary for sorting:

```
    def __gt__(self, other):
        if self.size_32 is not None:
            return self != other
        elif self.size_16 is not None:
            return False if other.size_32 is not None else True
        else:
            return False
```

If you want the values of the same types to be sorted, you will have to add another level of nesting to compare these values.

Comment: never rely on the implementation detail that python sorting only uses `__lt__` you can use `functools.total_ordering` to automate creating the other comparison methods once `__eq__` and one of them is defined.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about that. I am always paranoid that I made a silly mistake with the comparison operators, so automating the others would be much preferable than writing them all myself.

Comment: You are correct, in that case this seems much less flawed, but still `y = variableList(1, None, None) ; print(y<y)` prints True which is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for catching that.